# Ошибка Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPlayer' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Почему происходит эта ошибка ?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var player;
  var sdk;
  var ysdk;

  YaGames.init().then(ysdk => {
    console.log('Yandex SDK initialized');
    window.ysdk = ysdk;
  });

  ysdk.getPlayer(Тут отмечается ошибка)

  player.setData({
    Save: ['G.Egs'],
  }).then(() => {
    console.log('data is set');
  });
</script>
```

Я новичок и не очень понимаю, почему не работает

[Документация](https://yandex.ru/dev/games/doc/dg/sdk/sdk-player.html)

Comment: Я знаю, я ставил javascript, но выскакивала ошибка, мне просто не дали поставить правильно, так что прошу ногами не бить, ну, хотя бы не сильно :)

Comment: "но выскакивала ошибка" - какая ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка происходит потому что `ysdk` - не задан,
код ниже выполняется асинхронно

```js
YaGames.init().then(ysdk => {
  console.log('Yandex SDK initialized');
  window.ysdk = ysdk;
});
```

таким образом переменная `ysdk` на момент вызова еще не определена.

Ты можешь пропускать объекты которые не объявлены добавив `?` после объекта, в твоем случае `ysdk?.getPlayer`, но скорее всего это не решит проблему в твоем случае.

код ниже возможно решит твою проблему:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var player;
  var sdk;
  var ysdk;

  YaGames.init().then(ysdk => {
    console.log('Yandex SDK initialized');
    window.ysdk = ysdk;
    return Promise.resolve();
  }).then(
    () => {
      ysdk.getPlayer
        ...остальной код, выполнится после того как ysdk будет задан
    }
  )
</script>
```

аналогичным образом ты можешь дальше делать "паровозик" из `Promise` и `then`. Так же судя по документации которую ты предоставил функция `getPlayer()` тоже вернет `Promise` и ты можешь сделать примерно так

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var player;
  var sdk;
  var ysdk;

  YaGames.init().then(ysdk => {
    console.log('Yandex SDK initialized');
    window.ysdk = ysdk;
    return Promise.resolve();
  }).then(
    () => {
      return ysdk.getPlayer(параметры)
    }).then(
    () => {
      ...и так далее
    })
</script>
```

Comment: `return Promise.resolve();` не нужен, он и так его вернет.